# How do you make the connection with Facebook comment mirroring?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Earlier this year, Facebook released a new feature for developers called *[Comment mirroring](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments)*, where you basically could have comments posted on a shared link on Facebook being in sync with comments made on an external web page.

The documentation for it is very limited, though. I've been searching the web for more, but all I can find really is people talking *about* it, not *how to use* it. My problem is that I can't find how to make the connection from whenever I post an article on my Facebook page (e.g. called My articles), all the comments made on that post will show up on the article on my website (e.g. www.myarticles.com/the-article). Or have I completely misinterpreted the functionality?

Comment: Comment mirroring is still a Beta product that is currently only open to select partners. There is no way to request access to this Beta and Facebook will publish the documentation when it is publicly available. I would suggest keeping an eye on the [Developer Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog).

Comment: You can apply for the beta [here](https://developers.facebook.com/products/social-plugins/comments/). I did it one week ago but I didn't receive anything yet. Not even an automated message about my request being added to a queue or something.